# How to get the default vectors when drawing YUV with GLES2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, yuv

The program runs well in ios and and most Android devices,while, while,some Android devices will display with disorder,while,I can fix it by modify the values of the following two vectors.
My question is:
Is there  any smart way to know the vectors of devices? For example, by Surface, GPU...

```
static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,
};

static const GLfloat coordVertices[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f,  0.0f,
    1.0f,  0.0f,
};


glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(_program);

GLuint textureUniformY = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "SamplerY");
GLuint textureUniformU = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "SamplerU");
GLuint textureUniformV = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "SamplerV");
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);

glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXTURE, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, coordVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTURE);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you're seeing different behavior on different devices.  The OpenGLES spec defines how things behave; if you're issuing valid commands, they should behave the same everywhere.  My experience has been that, if one device is doing something weird, it's because I'm doing something wrong (like passing in uninitialized values) and it works out differently on different devices.

Comment: You are right. We target the program runs well on all Android devices, then we need set different values of "squareVertices" and "coordVertices" for each devices. How to avoid it?